# Left menu images changes on mouse hover

Tags: html, css

how can image change on mouse hover in left menu 
like below image without mouse hover

[image]

After on mouse hover we want to change image into white color. currently image not changed
[image]

Comment: there are two ways, 
you can put two img tags in your button container, and make the white one display none, so on hover action, you should make the colored one hidden and the other one visible,
the other way is using svg , you can change fill color property of an svg image with js.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with CSS.

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.optiontext {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hoverimage {
  display: none;
}

.option:hover>.image {
  display: none;
}

.option:hover>.hoverimage {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <div class="image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff0000/"></div>
  <div class="hoverimage"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/00ff00/"></div>
  <div class="optiontext">Settings</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How it working on mobile devices.In mobile devices hover effect not working